# How do I click a text button using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, button, xpath

Keep getting errors trying to click a specific button, I can use X path of the element to make it work, but I am working on a project that requires me to press on a a button from many other buttons, each x path is a random assortment of characters.

how do I click on a button using the text.

example of one of the elements I want to click:

```html
<div id="book_e43c607b-0fba-472e-ab84-7dd8ff6efb6b" class="time-slot"
     data-slotclub="calgary" data-slotdate="Saturday, 17 July 2021"
     data-slottime="at 5:00 PM">
    <div class="time-slot-clock"></div>
    <div class="time-slot-box">
        <div class="time-slot-data-line">Saturday, 17 July 2021</div>
        <div class="time-slot-data-line">at 5:00 PM</div>
        <div class="time-slot-data-line">Click to reserve</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a code that will click on the "at 5:00 PM" portion, and that can be change to accustom for other times (ex: "at 1:00 PM")

thank you

Comment: Well, if it is a random assortment of characters, then of course it is impossible.  If you had the outer `<div>`, you could choose the 2nd `time-slot-data-line` `<div> inside that.

Comment: What do you mean by that? So what should I do to address my issue?

Comment: Have you looked through the Javascript code enough to know which `<div>` that has been made clickable?

Comment: not sure how to tell